# drupal 7 advertising (or: I dislike the ad module anyway)

Tags: cck, ads, drupal-7

Hey folks!  Todays big question is this:

I have a Drupal gig coming up and I've decided to use D7!  Wow!  This is your basic ad driven magazine type site (the second I'll have done).  Unfortunatly:

- the ad module is not particularly powerful or flexible (for what i want it to do)
- it isn't ready for d7 anyway

SO:  I was wondering if anybody has endeavored to make cck behave as much as possible like the ad module with as few modules as possible, how well that worked out, and what problems you ran into.

"why" you may be asking "is the venerable ad module (if it worked in D7) not good enough for this man?"  Let me tell you.  (sure, I may be flat wrong on some of this stuff, but this is why I come to forum land)

- The ad module does not (seem) to handle free html ads very well.
- The ad module seems very keen to lock all of it's output into little blocks which I cannot design into very easily.
- The ad module is not CCKey as I would like.
- Ads cannot detect their context and behave differently (this iste has a lot of design "innovations"/weirdnesses)

What I /really/ want is a view of my ads, which I can load programatically, then node load each of it's elements and stick them all over the page an any way that I damn well please.

Problems I forsee doing ads through CCK:
- Getting ads to turn off after a certain number of views
- Managing ad frequency
- the things that i do not forsee.

TL;DR:  I wand an ad module alternative, probably just using CCK.
- has anybody done this?
- did it work ok?
- what unforseen difficulties did you have?
- how would you replace ad module specific features like ad frequency and depublication after a certain number of views.

Thanks People!

Answer (score 1):

This question is old but it came up in Google.

There is a new ad module that appears to be maintained well. From the project page:

[SimpleAds](http://drupal.org/project/simpleads) provides a way to manage advertisements on a Drupal 7 website. It displays graphical, text and flash ads in configurable blocks. It records and reports useful statistics. It is easy to configure and does not depend on other contrib modules.